# Login a website with jsoup in Java application

Tags: java, http, post, cookies, jsoup

I have read many post in this site and not only but nothing works for me. I want to create a java application to connect automaticaly at a website that need to post username, password and a cookie response to login. I give you the code I have tried and if someone could help me to correct it.

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect(uni_url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .execute();
    Map<String, String> cookies = res.cookies();


    Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(uni_url)
            .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
            .cookies(res.cookies())
            .data("uname", username1)
            .data("pass", password1)
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .get();
```

The result I take is the same login page.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using `.post()` instead of `.get()`?

Comment: @Pshemo Yes I have tried but it had the same result - Thank's for the fast reply

Comment: It'ts a little odd you are setting the method to POST, but using .get(). I would just stick to using .post() and not setting the method via .method().

Looking at the login site you listed, it looks like its also sending the submit button input along with the form data, so you could try adding another .data("submit", "Είσοδος") and see if that is why the login isn't working

Comment: @DangerDan Thank you very much! I make the changes that you wrote and it work nice!

Comment: If that solved your problem, please submit it as an answer and accept it, so this question does not appear in the unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup
                    .connect(uni_url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").execute();

Document doc2 = Jsoup.connect(uni_url)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
.cookies(res.cookies())
.data("uname", username1)
.data("pass", password1)
.data("submit", "")
.post();
```